# How can I get the actual culture name from an iPhone web app?

Tags: user-agent, globalization

CLARIFIED: This is a JavaScript Web Application not a Native Object-C application.

I have a web application running on the iPhone that I need to globalize.

I've configured Settings->General->International->Region Format to "United Kingdon" and left Language as "English".

Upon inspection of the User Agent string I'm seeing the following:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; **en-us**) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8A293

I would expect to en-GB but I'm seeing en-us.

I've even tried restarting the iPhone and it remains en-us.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the language portion comes from set type of your iPhone's "Language" (e.g. menus and buttons in the user interface) and not the Region Format.

[source](http://www.useragentstring.com/index.php?uas=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28iPhone%3B+U%3B+CPU+iPhone+OS+2_0_1+like+Mac+OS+X%3B+en-us%29+AppleWebKit%2F525.18.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F3.1.1+Mobile%2F5B108+Safari%2F525.20)

Comment: The language in the UserAgent string you posted is coming from the Browser; which if you're on the iPhone, comes from the iPhones "language" setting from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use NSUserDefaults to get that information

[ChoosingLocalizations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear as if the iPhone browser does not look at the region being set by the settings on the device.

The user agent and navigator.language both return en-US and disregard any changes to the region by the user.